# Why is the main page empty?

Tags: shopware

The question is already above. Which reasons can it have that the main page is empty?

The shopping worlds are configured properly. I have categories added and those categories contain articles which should be displayed on the main page of my shop.

Are there any other pitfalls I don't see?

Comment: Did you check for any errors showing up in either the Backend (check Configuration -> Logfile -> System log) or the JavaScript console when loading the main page?

Comment: Checked right now. Both are empty! :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no listing for the main page - so it won't display any products from child categories. The only way to display content on the homepage is a proper configured shopping world. Check the following things:

1. viewport configuration of the shopping world
2. Shop configuration of the shopping world
3. Assigned catgegory of the shopping world (should be the main category)
4. active/inactive state

If you can't find any issue with it, show us your configuration.